# Passing parameters through HTML buttons

Tags: html, xml, servlets, xslt

Is there a way to do this?

This is what I currently have:

```
<xsl:element name="a">
    <xsl:attribute name="href">InfoServlet?name=<xsl:value-of select="$vPrev_id"/></xsl:attribute>Previous Event
</xsl:element>
```

Is there a way to make this a button instead of a text link? I've tried a few things but can't seem to get it to work. I've tried this for example:

```
<form action="InfoServlet">
    <input class="btn btn-default btn-lg" type="submit" value="View Reviews"/>
    <xsl:attribute>InfoServlet?name=<xsl:value-of select="$name"/></xsl:attribute>
</form>
```

Comment: Will you have multiple values for $name  ?

Comment: In your first code block its $vPrev_id so you are having different variable to be used for name parameter ? Can you please elaborate

Comment: @ShaikhMohammedShariq Yes the parameter will have different values. It goes back to a previous node and displays that information.

Comment: On your page you will have only one link or button to submit to InfoServlet or there can be multiple ones ?

Comment: One button and each time you click it, the previous event is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try ..

```
<input type="button" />
```

?

Comment: `type="button"` will change the semantics. The browser will no longer submit the form. Also: your answer is a bit minimalistic and should maybe be a comment.

Comment: Sorry Max, have to have 50 rep or better to comment.  Additionally if you would like the button to submit the form try <input type="submit" value="Submit" />

Answer (score 0):

If you have one button than having one form on a document is fine. You can have it as shown below.

```
<form action='InfoServlet?name=<xsl:value-of select="$name"/>'>
    <input class="btn btn-default btn-lg" type="submit" value="View Reviews"/>
</form>
```

Comment: This yields this error: 

Exception transformation :The value of attribute "action" associated with an element type "null" must not contain the '<' character.

Comment: I have edited the answer to remove the attribute tag. You need to place the variable value only along with the URL of your servlet. Let me know.